# Filtering with java-streams - Find an occurrence of the Object with the matching property Nested inside Another Object

Tags: java, jpa, java-stream

I have `3` JPA **entities**: *projects*, *releases* and *resources*.

A *project* has many *releases*, and a *release* has many *resources*.

I am interested in finding all *releases* for a given *project*, where at least one of its *resources* belongs to a *given country*.

This is my attempt:

```
project.getProjectReleases().stream()
                .map(ProjectRelease::getRelease)
                .flatMap(release -> release.getTracks().stream())
                .map(Track::getResource)
                .filter(resource -> Country.US.name().equals(resource.getCountry())) //this is my doubt
                .flatMap(resource -> resource.getTracks().stream())
                .map(Track::getRelease)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This seems to be working, however I think I can't say this is exactly returning all releases for a given project, where at least one of its resources belongs to a given country since that filter will filter all resources where `country = 'US'`.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Write a unit test first.

Comment: The API suggests that it's many-to-many (`Resource::getTracks`, and `Track::getRelease`) what's extra confusing. Honestly speaking, a plain spelled out nested loop might be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

There are many transformations happening in the stream:

```
Project -> ProjectRelease -> Release -> Track -> Resource -> Track -> Release
```

And they are going in different "directions" which is not very intuitive.

You can introduce a separate method responsible for checking if any of the *resources* of a particular *release* belongs to a given *country*.

If I understood your logic correctly it can be written like that:

```
public static List<Release> getReleasesByCountry(Project project,
                                                 String countryName) {
    return project.getProjectReleases().stream()
        .map(ProjectRelease::getRelease)
        .filter(resource -> hasResourceByCountry(resource, countryName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static boolean hasResourceByCountry(Release release,
                                           String countryName) {
    
    return release.getTracks().stream()
        .map(Track::getResource)
        .anyMapth(resource -> countryName.equals(resource.getCountry()));
}
```